# NodeJS [ SailsJs ] Download a string as a file

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to take a string and download it as a file, without it saving to the file system.

Here is what I have.

```
res.attachment('hello.text');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
res.end("Hello, World", 'utf8');
```

I've also tried this:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=theDocument.txt');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
res.charset = 'UTF-8';
res.download("Hello, world");
res.end();
```

All these do is just return Hello World in the ajax response object. I want it to force a download.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to use:

```
res.download('.tmp/public/img/image.jpg');
```

Where the value passed to res.download is the path to the file that you want to send to the client.

Comment: Thats assuming I have the file to begin with.. I want to take a string and download it as a file, without it saving to the file system.